# How to create a numpy array for a black/white image?

Tags: python, numpy, dtype

If we want to create a numpy array from scratch for a RGB image, we can use
`arr = numpy.zeros([height, width, 3], dtype=numpy.uint8)`

But what dtype should be used to do the same for a black white image, i.e. the pixel value is either True or False?

Comment: `dtype='uint8'` is of the same size with `dtype=bool`. I'd just use `uint8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try this (`np.bool` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe.)

```
import numpy as np

height, width = 100, 100
bw_image = np.zeros([height, width], dtype=bool)
print(bw_image)
```

`bool` can be used as the dtype to represent a black and white image where each pixel can have values True (1) or False (0).

Comment: Your answer solves my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to create a numpy array for a black and white image you just need to add dtype=bool

```
height, width = 100, 100
image = np.zeros([100, 100], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I've tested with your solution, and it works. Thank you!